# How to use Count function based on standard value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It is categorized in A and B.

```
df :
Category    A      A      A       B       B 
CODE       U-01   U-02   U-03    U-04    U-05
n1          0      1      0       2       nan
n2          1      1      0       nan     nan
n3          3      0     nan       0       2
```

I want to count values based on standard value "0", ">0" and nan.

My desired output table would look like:

```
Category                 A                   B
Standard           0    >0    nan      0    >0     nan 
 n1                2     1     0       0     1      1
 n2                1     2     0       0     0      2
 n3                0     1     1       1     1      0
```

```
example) "n1-> Standard : 0 " is A&U-01, A&U-03 So, 2
```

Please help me,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape `DataFrame` for `Series with Multiindex`, then convert values gretaer like `0` to `>0`, replace missing values to string `nan` and count them by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.unstack()
         .mask(lambda x: x.gt(0), '>0')
         .fillna('nan')
         .groupby(level=[0, 2])
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([0,2], fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={0:'0'}))
print (df1)
Category  A         B       
          0 >0 nan >0 nan  0
n1        2  1   0  1   1  0
n2        1  2   0  0   2  0
n3        1  1   1  1   0  1
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve this error ? '`'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @democracii - yes, problem is soem values in some column are not numeric, need `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, error='coerce'))` for convert this values to `NaN`s, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: In this result, If there is no data in columns, it doesn't be expressed,,,

Comment: @democracii - so there is not some spaces before numbers? How working `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip(), error='coerce'))` ?

Comment: Yes it works! so I solved this problem. but  there is another problem. In my actual data, If n1,n2,n3 's  A & >0  value is nothing, It isn't expressed with column A&>0,,,

Comment: @democracii - Can you create new question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I created new question.

Comment: @democracii - Understand what need and added answers.